# store the values in a list from database

Tags: java

in my database there is a table called account .in this table 2 fields user and account number . the single user has multiple account number. i want to display all the account number of a particular user in my jsp page

Comment: Please explain further! Include a short example if possible. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is really general and not specific I would suggest you look at JDBC tutorial here: http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc.shtml (topic 8):
Retrieving Rows from database basics : http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/GetAllRows.shtml

Hope that helps. If not, please be specific in your question.

Comment: in my database there is a table called account .in this table 2 fields user and account number . the single user has multiple account number. i want to display all the account number of a particular user in my jsp page

Comment: Since there is no code supplied, the logic is that you should create a function that gets all the users and stores them in a list and iterate through the users using a function that gets user accounts (this function takes a user ID for example and returns a list of account the user has)

Answer (score 0):

Write a sql query
select account_no from account a with user_id in where clause 
outer join user u on u.user_id = a.user_id

iterate the result of this query and put each element into List. Make this list property of some java bean and use this bean on your jsp.